# Closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{2015}(-1)^{k(k+1)/2}k$

Tags: summation

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{2015}(-1)^\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\times k$$

How to solve this. Answer provided is $0$

Comment: When is $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ even? When is it odd? Note that $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=1+2+\cdots+k$. Try splitting the sum in the positive and negative terms.

Comment: See also: [Find the sum of finite series $S=\sum_{k=1}^{2015}{(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2295814).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\overbrace{-1-2+3+4}^4\overbrace{-5-6+7+8}^4\dots\overbrace{-2013-2014+2015+2016}^4=2016$

Take off the last $2016$, and we get

$\overbrace{-1-2+3+4}^4\overbrace{-5-6+7+8}^4\dots-2013-2014+2015=0$

Answer (score 2):

You get $-1-2 +3 +4 -5-6+7+8$ etc, so you get essentially $4+4+ \ldots 4 \ \  503 $ times + 3 more terms

Answer (score 1):

Note that if 
$$k=4n, n\in \mathbb N, 
(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}=(-1)^{2n(4n+1)}=1$$
$$k=4n+1, n\in \mathbb N, 
(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}=(-1)^{(2n+1)(4n+1)}=-1$$
$$k=4n+2, n\in \mathbb N, 
(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}=(-1)^{(4n+3)(2n+1)}=-1$$
$$k=4n+3, n\in \mathbb N, 
(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}=(-1)^{2(n+1)(4n+3)}=1$$

Thus, you can find the sum of four arithmetic progressions to solve the problem.