# Find the sum of finite series $S=\sum_{k=1}^{2015}{(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}k$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Find the sum $S=\sum_{k=1}^{2015}{(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}k.$

I partitioned k in two categories Either k is congruent to 0 , 3 mod(4) or congruent to 1,2 mod(4). But still I didn't get answer

Comment: This seems to be the same question as [Closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{2015}(-1)^{k(k+1)/2}k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1656497). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B2015%7D%7B(-1)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Bk(k%2B1)%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7Dk%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

Each group of four terms sum to $4$. Hence the sum to $4n$ terms equals $4n$, e.g.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2016}(-1)^{^{\frac {k(k+1)}2}}k=2016$$
and it follows that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2015}(-1)^{^{\frac {k(k+1)}2}}k=\sum_{k=1}^{2016}(-1)^{^{\frac {k(k+1)}2}}k-2016=\color{red}0$$

---

NB:  It is interesting to note the general case as follows:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{4n-1}(-1)^{^{\frac {k(k+1)}2}}k=\overbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{4n}(-1)^{^{\frac {k(k+1)}2}}k}^{=4n}-4n=0$$

Comment: Might be worthwhile noting that as $(-1)^{0(0+1)/2}*0 = 0$ that $\sum_{i=1}^{2015}(-1){k(k+1)/2}k = \sum_{i=0}^{2015}(-1){k(k+1)/2}k$ and so of you start and mod 0 rather than mod 4 then i) each group adds to 0 instead of 4, ii) your groups are complete, not incomplete.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, thanks, that's a good way of looking at it too.

Answer (score 2):

The sum is $\sum_{j=0}^{503}\sum_{k=4j}^{4j+3}(-1)^{k (k+1)/2}k$ (don't worry about $k=0$... it's equal to zero)

This is $\sum_{j=0}^{503}[4k-(4k+1)-(4k+2)+(4k+3)]=\sum_{j=0}^{503}0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The series is $-1-2+3+4-5-6+7+8-\cdots$. A quartet of four terms
$$-(4k-3)-(4k-2)+(4k-1)+(4k)$$
contributes $4$ to the sum, etc.

Comment: yes , but given answer is 0.

Comment: (0-1-2+3) + (4-5-6+7)+......+(2012-2013-2014+2015) = 0.  (-1-2+3+4)+(-5-6+7+8) + ...... +(-2009-2010+2011+2012) + (-2013-2014+2015 + 2016) = 4*504 = 2016.  But the sum ends at 2015 so  (-1-2+3+4)+(-5-6+7+8) + ...... +(-2009-2010+2011+2012) + (-2013-2014+2015) = 4*503 -2013-2014+2015 = 2012 -2013 -2014 + 2015 = 0.

Comment: @fleablood You said that in your answer!

Comment: Or  shorter.  The number and four each quartet.  But the last quartet is incomplete.  So doing it by quartets starting at 1 is 4*503 + (4 - 2016) = 0.  If you start at 0, however the quartets add to 0.  ANd the quartets are all complete.

Comment: No I didn't.  I am comparing the two methods and explaining how one answer can add 4 each time and still come up with 0 by not completing. I didn't mention that in my answer.