# Sum of integer sequence with occasional sign change $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2018}(-1)^{^{\binom {k+2}3}}k$

Tags: summation

This question was designed based on this other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295814/find-the-sum-of-finite-series).

> Evaluate $$\sum_{k=1}^{2018}(-1)^{^{\binom {k+2}3}}k$$
>   and explain why it would be a perfect square. Generalize.

Comment: the result is giveb by$$1018081$$

Comment: The sequence of the signs is $-1,+1,+1,+1$ . I hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 2):

We have that every $4$th term starting from the first is odd so numbers of the form $4k+1$ have a negative sign so we have that the sum is equal to. $$\sum_{k=1}^{4t+2}(-1)^{k+2\choose 3}k=\sum_{k=1}^{4t+2}k-2\sum_{k=0}^{t}(4k+1)=(2t+1)(4t+3)-4t(t+1)-2(t+1)=(2t+1)(4t+3)-2(t+1)(2t+1)=(2t+1)(4t+3-2t-2)=(2t+1)^2$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution (+1).

Answer (score 0):

**Sign change**

Note that $\displaystyle\binom {k+2}3=\frac{(k+2)(k+1)k}6$.

As $2$ is a factor of the denominator $6$ ,  $\displaystyle \binom {k+2}3$ is odd if the numerator has only one multiple of $2$ (but not of higher powers of $2$) in the denominator, and even otherwise.

- if $k$ is odd then,  $k+2$ is also odd and  only $k+1$ is even, and would be either

  (i) a multiple of $4$, in which case $\binom {k+2}3$ is **even**,

  or

  (ii) a multiple of $2$ but not of $4$, in which case $\binom {k+2}3$ is **odd** (as $2$ would cancel with $6$ leaving $3$ in the denominator and no more $2$'s left in the numerator. This occurs every $4r+1$ term.
- if $k$ is even then $k+2$ is also even, hence $\binom {k+2}3$ is **even**.

Hence the signs for $(-1)^{\binom {k+2}3}$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots$ are
$\color{red}-+++\color{red}-+++\color{red}-+++\color{red}-+++\cdots$

**Summation**

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{4m+2}(-1)^{\binom {k+2}3}k
&=-1+2+\sum_{r=1}^m (4r-1)+4r-(4r+1)+(4r+2)\\
&=1+\sum_{r=1}^m 8r\\
&=1+4m(m+1)\\
&=(2m+1)^2
\end{align}$$
Putting $m=504$ (note that $4\times 504+2=2018$) gives 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2018}(-1)^{\binom{k+2}3}k=\color{red}{1009^2}$$

---

**Special Note**

It is interesting to note that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{4m+3}(-1)^{\binom {k+2}3}k$ is also a perfect square. This is shown below.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{4m+3}(-1)^{\binom {k+2}3}k
&=-1+2+3+\sum_{r=1}^m 4r-(4r+1)+(4r+2)+(4r+3)\\
&=4+4\sum_{r=1}^m (2r+1)\\
&=4+4\left[(m+1)^2-1\right]
&&\scriptsize\text{as }(2r+1)=(r+1)^2-r^2\\
&=4(m+1)^2\\
&=\left[2(m+1)\right]^2\\
&=(2m+1)^2
\end{align}$$